# Laravel 5.1 Middleware users types redirections

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware

I am trying to make an app in Laravel 5.1.

In my users table I have 3 types of users, admin, agent and farmer. In the users table there is a column named user_type_id where admin is `user_type_id=1`, agent is `user_type_id=2` and farmer is `user_type_id=3`.

Admin has permission to do everything where agent has few permission.

Problem is while using middleware, my Authenticate.php and AgentAuthenticate.php middleware files are acting as if they are the same, meaning agent is getting all the powers of admin. is there any logical error?  here is the code.

agentAuthenticate.php (middleware)

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
            }
        }
        if(! $this->auth->user()->user_type != 2) {
         return redirect()->guest('auth/login');   
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Authenticate.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
            }
        }
        if(! $this->auth->user()->user_type != 1) {
         return redirect()->guest('auth/login');   
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

routes.php

```
 //guest routes
    Route::resource('/farmerPoint','farmerPointController',['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
    Route::resource('/crop','cropController',['only' => ['index', 'show']]);

    //Admin routes
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('agent','agentController');
    Route::resource('farmer','farmerController');
    Route::resource('farmer.crop','farmerCropController');
    Route::resource('cropType','cropTypeController');
    Route::resource('crop','cropController',['except' => ['index','show']]);
    Route::resource('farmerPoint','farmerPointController',['except' => ['index','show']]);
    Route::get('/AdminPanel',function(){
       return view('frontend.AdminPanel');
      });
    });
    //agent routes
       Route::group(['middleware' => 'agent'], function () {
       Route::resource('farmer','farmerController');
       Route::resource('farmer.crop','farmerCropController');
       Route::resource('agent','agentController',['only' => ['index','show']]);
       Route::get('/AgentPanel',function(){
        return view('frontend.AgentPanel'); 
       });
    });
```

Comment: wait a minute, is this `Authenticate.php` is the one shipped with laravel (`/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`) ? if so, yes, it'll behave that way as that controller is actually used for authentication. it also implements `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;` so, i can only suggest your admin have a different middleware (just like your `agent`), use `Authenticate.php` as a main authentication middleware. So, to guard your routes, you had to enclose the route with at least two `Route::group` - one for authentication, the other for segregations/roles.

Answer (score 0):

In `Authenticate.php` it should be:

```
if($this->auth->user()->user_type != 1) {
   return redirect()->guest('auth/login');   
}
```

because you want to make redirection for all users with type different than admin

And in `agentAuthenticate.php` it should be:

```
if(!in_array($this->auth->user()->user_type, [1,2])) {
   return redirect()->guest('auth/login');   
}
```

because you want to make redirection for all users with type different than agent but if user is admin you don't want to make redirection too (you mentioned `Admin has permission to do everything`)